# Automatically Tag Amazon EBS Snapshots with Tags taken from the Volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, amazon-ebs

I am looking for a way to tag the Amazon EBS snapshots with the tags of the volumes.

When I am creating a new manual snapshot from an Amazon EBS Volume, it has to be tagged automatically with the Volume Tags.

Please suggest ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do this is by setting up [Cloudwatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html) to trigger a Lambda function that will tag your snapshots.

For detailed example of what that might look like, See: [How to Automatically Tag Amazon EC2 Resources in Response to API Events | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-automatically-tag-amazon-ec2-resources-in-response-to-api-events/)

Answer (score 1):

From [Copy Snapshot API now supports adding tags while copying snapshots](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/copy-snapshot-api-supports-adding-tags-while-copying-snapshots/):

> Posted On: Nov 19, 2019
>
> You can now add tags while copying snapshots. Previously, a user had to first copy the snapshot and then add tags to the copied snapshot manually. Moving forward, **you can specify the list of tags you wish to be applied to the copied snapshot as a parameter on the Copy Snapshot API.**

This allows the tags to be copied **when the snapshot is initiated via an API call.** For example, you could trigger the snapshot via an AWS CLI command.

If, instead, you wish to automatically copy the tags when the snapshot is triggered via the Amazon EC2 management console, you would either need to manually specify the tags, or write some code that uses Amazon CloudWatch Events to notice that a new snapshot was created and copy the tags (as per @Calvin's answer).

Comment: You would need to write the Lambda function such that it extracts information about the volume that was specified during the Snapshot command, then copies it to the snapshot. This information is made available in the Trail record, but still needs the additional `DescribeVolume()` call to get that data. (Or, you could simply trigger the snapshot via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), specifying the tags you want copied to the snapshot.)